# Getting the file size of a text file without opening in binary mode

Tags: c++, file, filesize

I'm trying to get the size of a **text** file in c++.
I know that you can seek to the end of the file, then do `file.tellg()`, but I read it doesn't work in files opened in text mode.
Do I have to open it in binary mode then? And then what? Open it again in text mode? That doesn't seem very efficient...

Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the stat system call. It will return this information along with many other info in a struct.

Comment: this might work for you: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1417

Comment: `man 2 stat` would be a good place to start.

Comment: stat worked. Thanks to all the people who suggested it.